# How to Test Significance of Trading Strategy?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, experiment-design, finance

I am wanting to try out a new trading strategy, and it has proven successful on a simulator for the past few days. I do want to collect some more data and see if my results are statistically significant (ideally using a t-test), but I don't really know how to approach this (don't know what I would compare my trades to, or how I would set a 'control' trade).

Any help would be appreciated! Don't have a big background in stats, so go easier with the terminology, but I do have a strong background in other areas of math, so somewhat complex ideas are fine.

Comment: I wasn't aware that traders had any interest in statistical significance.  Isn't the whole point just to make money??

Comment: I want to check that the chance that this strategy making me money these past 5 trades is a false positive is smaller than (say) 1%. If I manage to do that, then I will start making larger trades with this strategy!

Comment: Out of the top of my head: the returns you get per trade are a time series right? A test that would make sense is to test if the average return per trade is statistically different from zero - actually statistically above zero. However, don't forget about errors of the first type (i.e. signifiance when there is none) and that (frequentist) statistical tests are based *conditioned* on the null hypothesis, i.e. under the assumptions that H0 holds (in this case that the average return is 0). Also, I wouldn't base any type of action on just 5 observations. Maybe after 100 or so :)

Comment: Using a t test on a dataset as small as $n=5$ would be inappropriate unless you are sure gains (and losses?) are normally distributed. You could use a nonparametric test [e.g., one-sample Wilcoxon (signed-rank) test or a sign test], but with only five trades you could not reject the null hypothesis that the average trade nets you \$0 at significance level anywhere near1%. Furthermore if your five trades were close together in time, they may not be a random sample to be used as a guide for future behavior. // If you could supply additional information, that might be helpful.

Comment: I want to obviously get a bigger data set, ideally n>200, but once I have that what would I do with that data? What would I compare it to?

Comment: As @BruceET alluded to in his comment, the time series nature of the data complicates the testing. You can stick observations into a software package’s t-test, but the result of that test is quite dubious when the independence assumption is violated.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some numerical examples to illustrate my comment:

Data sampled using R:

```
set.seed(2020)
x = round(rexp(5,.001),2)
x
[1]  293.81 1270.05  237.00  739.85 1419.52
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  237.0   293.8   739.9   792.0  1270.0  1419.5
```

One-sample t test (not valid because data not normal):

```
t.test(x)

    One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 3.2591, df = 4, p-value = 0.03111
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  117.2924 1466.7996
sample estimates:
mean of x 
  792.046
```

Nonparametric one-sample Wilcoxon test. P-value 0.0625 (smallest possible
for $n = 5);$ not significant at 1% level.

```
wilcox.test(x)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  x
V = 15, p-value = 0.0625
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
```

From Minitab, a sign test (same data): Also gives P=value 0.0625.

```
Sign Test for Median: Gain 

Sign test of median =  0.00000 versus ≠ 0.00000

      N  Below  Equal  Above       P  Median
Gain  5      0      0      5  0.0625   739.9
```